# How to directly use SciPy source code without building or installing it?

Tags: python, scipy

For some reason, I need to run my code on a machine that has numpy but not scipy. I tried to copy the `scipy` directory from [official git repo](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) to the directory of my code, but got import errors when running my code.

What is the correct way to do this?

PS: My code would be run in a docker container (not controlled by me) with read-only file system. So the desirable solution is to pack everything necessary in the beginning. I also tried `pip install scipy -t .` but it somehow doesn't work on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages via the command line by entering:

Installing via pip

python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose

or

brew install numpy scipy ipython jupyter

[Link](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

For Docker

[Alpine Docker Image for SciPy](https://hub.docker.com/r/alectolytic/scipy/)

docker run --rm -it alectolytic/scipy:latest python

Comment: I cannot use pip to install packages. Please read the question description, I have updated it.

Comment: docker run --rm -it alectolytic/scipy:latest python This image provides a lightweight (note this is used loosely when compared to the based image) runtime environment for SciPy codebases. This is an interim measure while the py-numpy, py-matplotlib and py-scipy available

Comment: I need to pack my code into a zipfile and send it to "someone else" who runs my code in a docker container. I have no control over using which docker image.

Comment: PyInstaller freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX. https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: is there a way to make the entry point still a python file instead of a binary?